# Tableau Extract API with multiple tables in a database

Tags: postgresql, tableau-api

I am currently experimenting with Tableau Extract API to generate some TDE from the tables I have in a PostgreSQL database.  I was able to write a code to generate the TDE from single table, but I would like to do this for multiple joined tables.  To be more specific, if I have two tables that are inner joined by some field, how would I generate the TDE for this?

I can see that if I am working with small number of tables, I could use a SQL query with JOIN clauses to create a one gigantic table, and generate the TDE from that table.

```
>> SELECT * FROM table_1 INNER JOIN table_2 
   INTO new_table_1 
   ON table_1.id_1 = table_2.id_2;

>> SELECT * FROM new_table_1 INNER JOIN TABLE_3
   INTO new_table_2
   ON new_table_1.id_1 = table_3.id_3
```

and then generate the TDE from new_table_2.

However, I have some tables that have over 40 different fields, so this could get messy.

Is this even a possibility with current version of the API?

Answer (score 2):

You can read from as many tables or other sources as you want. Or use complex query with lots of joins, or create a view and read from that. Usually, creating a view is helpful when you have a complex query joining many tables.

The data extract API is totally agnostic about how or where you get the data to feed it -- the whole point is to allow you to grab data from unusual sources that don't have pre-built drivers for Tableau.

Since Tableau has a Postgres driver and can read from it directly, you don't need to write a program with the data extract API at all.  You can define your extract with Tableau Desktop. If you need to schedule automated refreshes of the extract, you can use Tableau Server or its tabcmd command.

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks for your replies.  I am aware that I could use Tableau Desktop to define my extract.  In fact, I have done this many times before.  I am just trying to create the extracts using the API, because I need to create some calculated fields, which is near impossible to create using the Tableau Desktop.

At this point, I am hesitant to use JOINs in the SQL query because the resulting table would look too complicated to comprehend (some of these tables also have same field names).

When you say that I could read from multiple tables or sources, does that mean with the Tableau Extract API?  At this point, I cannot find anywhere in this API that accommodates multiple sources.  For example, I know that when I use multiple tables in the Tableau Desktop, there are icons on the left hand side that tells me that the extract is composed of multiple tables.  This just doesn't seem to be happening with the API, which leaves me stranded.  Anyways, thank you again for your replies.

Answer (score 1):

Going back to the topic, this is something that I tried few days ago on my python code

```
try:
    tdefile= tde.Extract("extract.tde")
except:
    os.remove("extract.tde")
    tdefile = tde.Extract("extract.tde")

tableDef = tde.TableDefinition()

# Read each column in table and set the column data types using tableDef.addColumn
# Some code goes here...    

for eachTable in tableNames:
    tableAdd = tdeFile.addTable(eachTable, tableDef)

    # Use SQL query to retrieve bunch_of_rows from eachTable

    for some_row in bunch_of_rows:
    # Read each row in table, and set the values in each column position of each row
    # Some code goes here...
    tableAdd.insert(some_row)
    some_row.close()

tdefile.close()
```

When I execute this code, I get the error that eachTable has to be called "Extract".

Of course, this code has its flaws, as there is no where in this code that tells how each table are being joined.

So I am little thrown off here, because it doesn't seem like I can use multiple tables unless I use JOINs to generate one table that contains everything.

Comment: You seem to misunderstand Tableau data sources. A data source is always a single "table" from Tableau's point of view. It has a fixed set of columns and arbitrary rows. The data source may obtain its input data in different ways: from a single database table or view, or byjoining multiple database tables, or by custom sql. But the datasource output is a single table. For convenience, when you use joins from Tableau, the user interface displays the original table names by field names, but a data source still results in exactly one table.An extract is simply a snapshot of a data source.

Comment: My comment above is a little off. A data connection still presents a single table like structure to Tableau, but an extract can can contain multiple tables.